# Why to use Promise.resolve().then()?

Tags: javascript, angular

While reading Angular's code for the directive [RouterLinkActive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L147), I found a curious usage of `Promise.resolve`:

```js
  private update(): void {
    ...
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      const hasActiveLinks = this.hasActiveLinks();
      if (this.isActive !== hasActiveLinks) {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
```

In which case is it useful to use `Promise.resolve().then()` instead of just executing the code that is inside of the `then`?

I've seen usages of `setTimeout(() => defeferedFunction())` but first time seeing it with  `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: It *might* be the same as `setTimeout(() => defeferedFunction())` but only using a promise for that (and thus the microtask queue). However, I'm not sure it's really possible to say exactly why it was used there. Might be a mistake or it might be intentional. It might be intentional but misguided for one reason or another.

Comment: Note that Angular has a [Discord server](https://discord.com/invite/angular) set up for just these kinds of questions, where the general population can guess (as the existing one does), but it might be better to get the answer from the people who wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular framework does this a lot. It is used to prevent an error that you will see a lot (sorry don't know the actual wording of the error) something like 'The value was changed after it was checked'. This error happens if the Change Detector checked a value and then it was changed in the same cycle.

The Promise.resolve() pushes this code on to the microtask queue so it is executed after the JavaScript stack is empty. This prevents the error.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your function to return a promise, but you only conditionally run code that involves promises, you may want to use this pattern.

Alternatively, just use `async/await` syntax.

So for example, if you have a function to fetch data, but the data may be cached, you can do something like

```js
function fetchData() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    if (cache && cache.data) return cache.data;
    
    // if we're here, the data isn't cached.
    return database.getData();
  })
}
```

This way, it ALWAYS returns a promise that always resolves with the data you want, even when you're using the sychronous cache code

Comment: There's no `return` in the code that the OP is asking about. While you're correct in general (this can be a use case for `Promise.resolve()`), it's not the reason here.

Comment: Furthermore the OPs code is typescript and has `: void` on the method definition, so they have expressly shown that there should not be a return at all.

Comment: OPs code is omitting a lot of stuff. The principle of my answer still might apply, if for example the latter part of the function expects a promise from the earlier part of the function, but the earlier part of the function might conditionally use sync or async code. It's hard to say, because he gave us so little to look at.

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms, inside a then handler function:

A) When x is a value (number, string, etc):

`return x` is equivalent to `return Promise.resolve(x)`
`throw x` is equivalent to `return Promise.reject(x)`

B) When x is a Promise that is already settled (not pending anymore):

`return x` is equivalent to `return Promise.resolve(x)`, if the Promise was already resolved.
`return x` is equivalent to `return Promise.reject(x)`, if the Promise was already rejected.

C) When x is a Promise that is pending:

`return x` will return a pending Promise, and it will be evaluated on the subsequent then.

Comment: I'm not sure how that explanation helps with the code in the question. Especially since we don't actually know what that code is doing.